# Simple File I/O in Visual Basic 2013

Tags: vb.net, file

I want to learn how to write and read data from files using Visual Basic Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop.

Specifically, I have a class called Pilots. The class includes text of a first and last name, and integers representing rank, skill, missions and status.

There is an ArrayList called Squadron that contains 18 (at start) Pilots.

What I want to do is save and then load all the data in Squadron to a file. And I'm not sure how to get it to work properly. I've read numerous books and sites, but somewhere along the line, I'm just not comprehending how to get it to work correctly.

At this point, I've been able to write the data to a file.... but I'm having no luck getting it back out of the file.

To write it out... I'm using this code:

```
    Dim currentpilot As New Pilot("John", "Doe")
    ' Create the BinaryWriter and use File.Open to create the file.
    Using writer As BinaryWriter = New BinaryWriter(File.Open("squadron.dat", FileMode.Create))
        ' Write each integer.
        writer.Write(SquadronList.Count)
        For index = 0 To SquadronList.Count - 1
            currentpilot = CType(SquadronList(index), Pilot)
            writer.Write(currentpilot.pFirstName)
            writer.Write(currentpilot.pLastName)
            writer.Write(currentpilot.pSkill)
            writer.Write(currentpilot.pRank)
            writer.Write(currentpilot.pStatus)
            writer.Write(currentpilot.pMissions)
            writer.Write(currentpilot.pKills)
        Next
    End Using
```

The `writer.Write(SquadronList.Count)` line is there to record the number of actual Pilot records in the file. I don't know if that's necessary or not.

The file does write to disk and just looking at it with notepad, it does seem to have the correct data.

The problem is getting it back out. This code fails quickly...

```
            Using reader As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(File.OpenRead("squadron.dat"))
        Dim index As Integer = reader.ReadInt32
        For counter = 0 To index - 1
            currentpilot.pFirstName = reader.ReadString
            currentpilot.pLastName = reader.ReadString
            currentpilot.pSkill = reader.ReadInt16
            currentpilot.pRank = reader.ReadInt16
            currentpilot.pStatus = reader.ReadInt16
            currentpilot.pMissions = reader.ReadInt16
            currentpilot.pKills = reader.ReadInt16
            SquadronList.Add(currentpilot)
        Next
    End Using
```

So... any suggestions or guidance will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using System.IO.streamreader instead of binaryreader?

Comment: How about xml serialization? Then you can save and read these files into your class object.

Comment: ReadInt16() is pretty unlikely to work correctly, it almost surely wasn't written with the BinaryWriter.Write(Int16) overload.  You'd have to use CShort() explicitly in the Write() call to ensure it is a match.  Or use the correct Read version that matches the property type.  There are certainly better ways to do this, using binary or XML serialization.

Comment: DonA... xml serialization is probably a much better route... and I can write the ArrayList of Pilot objects out to an XML file... but I'm not able to read the file back into an ArrayList of Pilot objects.  Still missing something here.

Comment: You should try Serialization better than this. SquadronList is a List(Of Pilot) ?? See the 2nd answer here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/06744366-c956-4e92-ace5-cd1fd5944232/writing-to-an-xml-vbnet?forum=vbgeneral